# Angular 4 with ngrx and sessionStorrage on ie11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, ngrx, sessionstorage

I have an angular 4 app based on ngrx. My informations are fetched from an endpoint using an angular interceptor and it saves the token on sessionStorage to update each http calls.

Somehow, I see that on ie11, on local angular-cli app, all the informations are good. All the calls are perfect. If I login and consume some data from an API, then logout and login back with a different user all informations are updated according to the logged user.

BUT, on the same application added on the server, if I login and fetch some datas, then logout, and then login back with a different username, I'm getting all the datas of the first logged username. In the same time, if I just close the browser (not the tab), normally it gets refreshed.

On the network request, I'm seeing that is always sending the initial token, even if I'm always changing it and listen it.

On logout, I'm reseting my sessionStorages so I can logout the user on each window close.

Question: **Does anyone knows if the sessionStorage methods have some issues with getItem method, or setItem, or somehow if anyone have some clues over what should be the problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a local state being persisted in ngrx? Sounds like local state is being reused rather than from session storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to find the problem. It seems that internet explorer 11 is making a cache over each request that is repeated from the same server. It was working on my local machine because the call was made from localhost to a server, and not from the server to itself. 
I had to force each call to be a new one without any cache from the interceptor.

Thanks!

Hopefully will it help anyone!

Answer (score 0):

internet explorer get data from cache after every GET call, you have to prevent getting data from cache that, i've added this in http header and it works great:

```
const apiHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
 'Pragma': 'no-cache',
 'Expires': '-1'
 });

...
...
return this.http.get(uri, { headers: apiHeaders}):
...
```